# JS Promise Trouble

Tags: javascript, promise

Недавно решил познакомится с промисами. Решил написать такой код. Проверил дебагером, получается бесконечный цикл. Код недоходит до вложенного promices.next(result). Почему?

```js
function async(generator) {
    let promices = generator();
    let pr = Promise.resolve();

    function f() {
        
        let currentGenObject = promices.next();

        while (!(currentGenObject.done)) {
            pr = pr.then((result) => {
                currentGenObject = promices.next(result);
                return currentGenObject.value;
            });
        }
    }
    return pr.then(f);
}
```

Comment: добавь пример вызова своей функции

Comment: ну и да, ты постоянно крутишься в цикле и твои then не успевают отработать, чтобы изменить значение `currentGenObject`, соответственно у тебя постоянно значение `!(currentGenObject.done)` - вот и бесконечный цикл

Comment: и еще стоит описать пример ожидаемого поведения, сейчас не совсем понятно как именно все должно работать